# group by on scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy sparse matrix with 10e6 rows and 10e3 columns, populated to 1%. I also have an array of size 10e6 which contains keys corresponding to the 10e6 rows of my sparse matrix. I want to group my sparse matrix following these keys and aggregate with a sum function.

Example:

```
Keys:
['foo','bar','foo','baz','baz','bar']

Sparse matrix:
(0,1) 3              -> corresponds to the first 'foo' key
(0,10) 4             -> corresponds to the first 'bar' key
(2,1) 1              -> corresponds to the second 'foo' key
(1,3) 2              -> corresponds to the first 'baz' key
(2,3) 10             -> corresponds to the second 'baz' key
(2,4) 1              -> corresponds to the second 'bar' key

Expected result:
{
    'foo': {1: 4},               -> 4 = 3 + 1
    'bar': {4: 1, 10: 4},        
    'baz': {3: 12}               -> 12 = 2 + 10
}
```

What is the more efficient way to do it?

I already tried to use `pandas.SparseSeries.from_coo` on my sparse matrix in order to be able to use pandas group by but I get this known bug:

```
site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy)
    863         for obj in objs:
    864             if not isinstance(obj, NDFrame):
--> 865                 raise TypeError("cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object")
    866 
    867             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Comment: Is there an element in the `keys` list for each nonzero element in the matrix?  As presented the problem looks more like a list and dictionary (`dok` format sparse?) problem than an array/matrix one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can generate your target with basic dictionary and list operations:

```
keys = ['foo','bar','foo','baz','baz','bar']
rows = [0,0,2,1,2,2]; cols=[1,10,1,3,3,4]; data=[3,4,1,2,10,1]
dd = {}
for i,k in enumerate(keys):
    d1 = dd.get(k, {})
    v = d1.get(cols[i], 0)
    d1[cols[i]] = v + data[i]
    dd[k] = d1
print dd
```

producing

```
{'baz': {3: 12}, 'foo': {1: 4}, 'bar': {10: 4, 4: 1}}
```

I can generate a sparse matrix from this data as well with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)))
print M
print
Md = M.todok()
print Md
```

But notice that the order of terms is not fixed.  In the `coo` the order is as entered, but change format and the order changes.  In other words the match between `keys` and the elements of the sparse matrix is unspecified.

```
  (0, 1)    3
  (0, 10)   4
  (2, 1)    1
  (1, 3)    2
  (2, 3)    10
  (2, 4)    1

  (0, 1)    3
  (1, 3)    2
  (2, 1)    1
  (2, 3)    10
  (0, 10)   4
  (2, 4)    1
```

Until you clear up this mapping, the initial dictionary approach is best.