# Group by sparse matrix in scipy and return a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, nlp

There are a few questions on SO dealing with using `groupby` with sparse matrices. However the output seem to be lists, [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410839/group-by-on-scipy-sparse-matrix), [dataframes](http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/30295570/groupby-sum-sparse-matrix-in-pandas-or-scipy-looking-for-performance?rq=1) and other objects.

I'm working on an NLP problem and would like to keep all the data in sparse scipy matrices during processing to prevent memory errors.

Here's the context:

I have vectorized some documents ([sample data here](http://andrewbrown.ca/data/groupbysparsematrix%20.csv)):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv('groupbysparsematrix.csv')
docs = df['Text'].tolist()

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
train_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

print("Dimensions of training set: {0}".format(train_X.shape))
print type(train_X)

Dimensions of training set: (8, 180)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

From the original dataframe I use the date, in a day of the year format, to create the groups I would like to sum over:

```
from scipy import sparse, hstack    

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
groups = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%j'))
groups_X = sparse.csr_matrix(groups.astype(float)).T
train_X_all = sparse.hstack((train_X, groups_X))

print("Dimensions of concatenated set: {0}".format(train_X_all.shape))

Dimensions of concatenated set: (8, 181)
```

Now I'd like to apply `groupby` (or a similar function) to find the sum of each token per day. I would like the output to be another sparse scipy matrix.

The output matrix would be 3 x 181 and look something like this:

```
 1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 1, 3
 2, 1, 3, ..., 1, 1, 4
 0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 2, 5
```

Where the columns 1 to 180 represent the tokens and column 181 represents the day of the year.

Comment: Are you talking about the `pandas` `groupby`?  Can you give a working example with dense arrays?  There is a pandas sparse format, but it's interaction with sparse matrix is still under development.

Comment: Column 181 - is that sparse or not?

Comment: column 181 (groups_X) is a `scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix` but in reality it is dense given that each observation has a date.

Answer (score 6):

The best way of calculating the sum of selected columns (or rows) of a `csr` sparse matrix is a matrix product with another sparse matrix that has 1's where you want to sum.  In fact `csr` sum (for a whole row or column) works by matrix product, and index rows (or columns) is also done with a product (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500986/901925)

So I'd group the dates array, and use that information to construct the summing 'mask'.

For sake of discussion, consider this dense array:

```
In [117]: A
Out[117]: 
array([[0, 2, 7, 5, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 7],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 0, 8, 1, 0, 9, 0, 2, 4],
       [9, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 7],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 4, 7],
       [3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]])
```

Make a sparse copy:

```
In [118]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

generate some groups, based on the last column; `collections.defaultdict` is a convenient tool to do this:

```
In [119]: grps=defaultdict(list)
In [120]: for i,v in enumerate(A[:,-1]):
     ...:     grps[v].append(i)

In [121]: grps
Out[121]: defaultdict(list, {0: [1, 2, 4, 9], 2: [8], 4: [3, 5], 7: [0, 6, 7]})
```

I can iterate on those groups, collect rows of `M`, sum across those rows and produce:

```
In [122]: {k:M[v,:].sum(axis=0) for k, v in grps.items()}
Out[122]: 
{0: matrix([[0, 0, 4, 8, 7, 2, 7, 6, 8, 0]], dtype=int32),
 2: matrix([[3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=int32),
 4: matrix([[4, 7, 6, 8, 1, 5, 9, 0, 3, 8]], dtype=int32),
 7: matrix([[ 9,  2, 15, 10,  2,  7,  2,  8, 13, 21]], dtype=int32)}
```

In the last column, values include 2*4, and 3*7

So there are 2 tasks - collecting the groups, whether with this defaultdict, or `itertools.groupby` (which in this case would require sorting), or `pandas` groupby.  And secondly this collection of rows and summing.  This dictionary iteration is conceptually simple.

A masking matrix might work like this:

```
In [141]: mask=np.zeros((10,10),int)
In [142]: for i,v in enumerate(A[:,-1]): # same sort of iteration
     ...:     mask[v,i]=1
     ...:     
In [143]: Mask=sparse.csr_matrix(mask)
...
In [145]: Mask.A
Out[145]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       ....
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
In [146]: (Mask*M).A
Out[146]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  8,  7,  2,  7,  6,  8,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  7,  6,  8,  1,  5,  9,  0,  3,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  2, 15, 10,  2,  7,  2,  8, 13, 21],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

This `Mask*M` has the same values as the dictionary row, but with the extra 0s.  I can isolate the nonzero values with the `lil` format:

```
In [147]: (Mask*M).tolil().data
Out[147]: 
array([[4, 8, 7, 2, 7, 6, 8], [], [3, 1, 2], [],
       [4, 7, 6, 8, 1, 5, 9, 3, 8], [], [],
       [9, 2, 15, 10, 2, 7, 2, 8, 13, 21], [], []], dtype=object)
```

I can construct the `Mask` matrix directly using the `coo` sparse style of input:

```
Mask = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(A.shape[0],int),
    (A[:,-1], np.arange(A.shape[0]))), shape=(A.shape))
```

That should be faster and avoid the memory error (no loop or large dense array).

Comment: Great solutions. These work well on small data sets but are there alternations that would allow them to be applied to larger datasets? My particular problem is a (69424, 685296) sparse matrix. jupyter hangs when I attempt `{k:M[v,:].sum(axis=0) for k, v in grps.items()}` and I get a MemoryError when I attempt to make a (69424, 685296) mask of zeros.

Comment: I added a method of constructing the group Mask matrix directly with the `coo` style of inputs.

Comment: I have tried your edits with the sample A data and my own data but I receive a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` I have searched SO and tried to solve the problem by changing the data type and rearranging the syntax but can't get it to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd have to see the error stack.  Normally that error is produced by a statement like `x[i] = np.array([1,2,3])` where `x` is 1d.  The the RHS expects a scalar value, but the LHS is giving an array or list (i.e. sequence).  So something has more dimensions than expected.

Comment: Thanks  for your help. The problem with the `csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=())` solution is that it uses `A` which is a np array. If you try it with `M` - the csr matrix - you get the `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. My thinking is any solution that employs dense matrices will fail on large datasets.

Comment: Can you use the date column in its dense form?  `M[:,-1].A.ravel()` or `groups` before the `csr` conversion and `hstack`?  We could also work form the sparse form, but you said this was dense anyways, a date for row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124087/discussion-between-andrew-brown-and-hpaulj).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick using `LabelBinarizer` and matrix multiplication.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
lb = LabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
grouped = lb.fit_transform(groups).T.dot(train_X)
```

`grouped` is the output sparse matrix of size 3 x 180. And you can find the list of its groups in `lb.classes_`.